# OpenCL select/delete points from large array

Tags: opencl

I have an array of 2M+ points (planned to be increased to 20M in due course) that I am running calculations on via OpenCL. I'd like to delete any points that fall within a random triangle geometry.

How can I do this within an OpenCL kernel process?

*I can already:*

- identify those points that fall outside the triangle (simple point in poly algorithm in the kernel)
- pass their coordinates to a global output array.

*But*:

- an openCL global output array cannot be variable and so I initialise it to match the input array of points in terms of size
- As a result, 0,0 points occur in the final output when a point falls within the triangle
- The output array therefore does not result in any reduction per se.

Can the 0,0 points be deleted within the openCL context?

n.b. I am coding in OpenFrameworks, so c++ implementations are linking to .cl files

Comment: How about sort by key (where key is zero/one based on whether the corresponding point belongs to the triangle) to move the points of interest to the beginning of the points vector, followed by sum over key vector to find out how many points you need?

Comment: hmmm, in a similar way I've been wondering if I could do a reduce sum that gives me an 'n' total number of points kept (at the same time as testing to see if in the triangle), followed by a boost::sort back in the host file and then just a delete points 0-'n'. Seems long winded tho.

Comment: You could use a library that provides the necessary primitives. [Boost.compute](https://github.com/boostorg/compute) or [VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) are possible examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an alternative for the case where most of the points fall inside the atomic condition:

It is possible to have a local counter, and local atomic. Then to merge that atomic to the global value it is possible to use `atomic_add()`. Witch will return the "previous" global value. So, you just copy the indexes to that address and up.

It should be a noticeable speed up, since the threads will sync locally and only once globally. The global copy can be parallel since the address will never overlap.

For example:

```
__kernel mykernel(__global MyType * global_out, __global int * global_count, _global MyType * global_in){
   int lid = get_local_id(0);
   int lws = get_local_size(0);
   int idx = get_global_id(0);

   __local int local_count;
   __local int global_val;    
   //I am using a local container, but a local array of pointers to global is possible as well
   __local MyType local_out[WG_SIZE]; //Ensure this is higher than your work_group size
   if(lid==0){
      local_count = 0; global_val = -1;
   }
   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

   //Classify them
   if(global_in[idx] == ....)
       local_out[atomic_inc(local_count)] = global_in[idx];

   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

   //If not, we are done
   if(local_count > 0){
      //Only the first local ID does the atomic to global
      if(lid == 0)
         global_val = atomic_add(global_count,local_count);

      //Resync all the local workers here
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

      //Copy all the data
      for(int i=0; i<local_count; i+=lws)
          global_out[global_val+i] = local_out[i];
   }
}
```

*NOTE: I didn't compile it but should more or less work.*

Comment: I'm trying to write this as a kernel but it isn't quite working. Do local_count and local_out need to be arguments in the kernel void?

Comment: Sry it was just a prototype kernel, I never actually tested. Let me write down a proper one. In the meantime, local values are local witch means they are not passed in the kernel arguments.

Comment: two v. minor edits to anyone else who comes this way - a reference on the atomic_inc(&local_count) and i++ rather than i+=lws to scoop up all of the local results in the final output. Otherwise works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to use this approach within a kernel that has the run parameters of 4096 global size and 64 local size - does that mean the local ints get reset once the kernel hits the end of its max work items? I think that this is happening - which means it can't keep a track of the classified points over a very large set. Am I right and is there a solution?

Comment: The local values will get deleted after the work group has finished (64), but the global counter will still be there. After the 4096 work items in the global size finish the counter will still hold the counter, and you are free to launch another kernel or any other thing you need. BTW, launching only 4096 is slow for OpenCL.

Comment: Ok, I can launch for higher now. Buuut I'm still finding that using this local atomic_inc method is overall slower than just pushing the point ids (at the moment that they are filtered) to a global array using atomic_inc... odd

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem, you can do:

--> In your kernel, you can identify the points in the triangle and:

```
if(element[idx]!=(0,0))
      output_array[atomic_inc(number_of_elems)] = element[idx];
```

Finally, in first number_of_elems of output_array in the host you will have 
your inner points.

I hope this help you,
Best

Comment: please could you give a little more detail? what is the atomic_inc(number_of_elms)] taking a reference from?

Comment: You can modify your kernel signature to include: `,__global unsigned int* number_of_elems`. This global pointer should be 0 when the kernel is launched. As it is a global pointer, all the threads can access to it, so when a thread finds a point inside the triangle it increases the  number_of_elems counter doing number_of_elems++ (atomically using atomic_inc). You can use that global variable to store your points in the first positions of the output array.

Comment: I have atomic_inc working now (and I'm kicking myself because I tried a number_of_elems++ increment about five hours ago and got weird results - so near yet so far) - not sure what the atomic function does to the gpu speeds though. I guess it is a trade off between that and sorting the whole array afterwards... Will try working the increment into the setting of the output array elements and post back later - thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly with `returnPos[atomic_inc(&number_of_returns[0])] = see;` where returnPos is the output array. Then in the host file just limit the reading of the output to the final number_of_returns int. I think this is probably the quickest approach, as I don't need the final points sorted in any way. Thanks!

Comment: If your output data is sparse, this is a great solution. On the other hand, if most of your points survive then the atomic is going to be heavily contended and bottleneck.

Comment: :) my pleasure. BTW, as @Dithermaster says, the performance of this solution depends strongly of the number of elements inside the triangle, the higher the worse because if all the threads do the atomic operation, the kernel execution will be too sequential :/

Comment: I'm thinking reduction tactics work pretty well here. Because it does atomic_inc on each and every element, it heavily depends on the architecture how well this performs. Maybe this can be sped up, by splitting it up per workgroup? If you use `atomic_inc(number_of_elems[workgrpoupID])` you won't get slowdown with a large array, but... then you will need a third pass which copies the packed sub-arrays. I have no idea for what array sizes this will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are alternatives, all working better or worse, depending on how the data looks like. I put one below.

Deleting the identified points can also be done by registering them in a separate array per workgroup - you need to use the same atomic_inc as with Moises's answer (see my remark there about doing this at workgroup-level!!). The end-result is a list of start-points and end-points of parts that don't need to be deleted. You can then copy parts of the array those by different threads. This is less effective if you have clusters of points that need to be deleted