# OpenCL: Inserting local atomic_inc to reduction kernel

Tags: opencl

I am trying to include a local atomic similar to that described by DarkZeros [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517754/opencl-select-delete-points-from-large-array) within a working reduction kernel. The kernel finds a largest value within a set of points; the aim of the local atomic is to allow me to filter selected point_ids into an output array without any gaps.

At present when I use the local atomic to increment the addition to a local array the kernel runs but produces a wrong overall highest point. If the atomic line is commented out then a correct result returns.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Simplified kernel code:

```
__kernel void reduce(__global const float4* dataSet, __global const int* input, const unsigned int items,                                   //points and index
                    __global int* output, __local float4* shared, const unsigned int n,                                                 //finding highest
                        __global int* filtered, __global const float2* tri_input, const unsigned int pass,                              //finding filtered
                            __global int* global_count                                                                                  //global count
                                ){
//set everything up

const unsigned int group_id = get_global_id(0) / get_local_size(0);
const unsigned int local_id = get_local_id(0);
const unsigned int group_size = items;
const unsigned int group_stride = 2 * group_size;
const int local_stride = group_stride * group_size;

__local float4 *zeroIt = &shared[local_id];
zeroIt->x = 0; zeroIt->y = 0; zeroIt->z = 0; zeroIt->w = 0;

volatile __local int local_count_set_1;
volatile __local int global_val_set_1;
volatile __local int filter_local[64];

if(local_id==0){
    local_count_set_1 = 0;
    global_val_set_1 = -1;
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

int i = group_id * group_stride + local_id;

while (i < n){
//load up a pair of points using the index to locate them within a massive dataSet
    int ia = input[i];
    float4 a = dataSet[ia-1];

    int ib = input[i + group_size];
    float4 b = dataSet[ib-1];

    //on the first pass kernel increment a local count
    if(pass == 0){
        filter_local[atomic_inc(&local_count_set_1)] = 1;  //including this line causes an erroneous highest point result
        //filter_local[local_id] = 1; //but including this line does not
        //atomic_inc(&local_count_set_1); //and neither does this one
    }

    //find the highest of the pair
    float4 result;
    if(a.z>b.z) result = a;
    else result = b;

    //load up the previous highest result locally
    float4 s = shared[local_id];

    //if the previous highest beat this, stick, else twist
    if(s.z>result.z){ result = s; }
    shared[local_id] = result;
    i += local_stride;
}

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
if (group_size >= 512){
    if (local_id < 256) {
        __local float4 *a = &shared[local_id];
        __local float4 *b = &shared[local_id+256];
        if(b->z>a->z){  shared[local_id] = shared[local_id+256]; }
    }}

//repeat barrier ops in increments down to group_size>=2 - this filters the highest result in shared
//finally, return the filtered highest result of shared to the global level

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if(local_id == 0){
        __local float4 *v = &shared[0];
        int send = v->w ;
        output[group_id] = send+1;
    }}
```

[UPDATE]: When the atomic_inc line is included the 'wrong' highest point result is always a point near the end of the test dataset. I'm guessing that this means that the atomic_inc is affecting a latter comparison, but I'm not sure exactly what or where yet.

[UPDATE]: Edited code to simplify/clarify/update with debugging tweaks. Still not working and it is driving me loopy.

Comment: Try declaring the `filter_local_1` array as volatile. This is what OpenCL atomic functions expect: `__local volatile int filter_local_1[GROUP_SIZE];`

Comment: no, still get the same issues there. A little more investigation shows that whilst trying this line: `filter_local_1[get_local_id(0)] = &aW;` gives a normal result, this line: `filter_local_1[atomic_inc(&local_count_set_1)] = &aW;` gives a wrong 'un. Looking at the wrong result, it seems as though the highest point selector is returning the last high result rather than the overall highest... might be a clue there as to what the atomic_inc is affecting, but it is beyond me

Answer (score 1):

Total face-palm moment. In the setup phase of the kernel there are the lines:

```
if(local_id==0){
   local_count_set_1 = 0;
   global_val_set_1 = -1;
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

When these are split and the local_count_set_1 is included within the while loop, the error does not occur. i.e:

```
if(local_id==0) global_val_set_1 = -1;
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

while (i < n){
    if(local_id==0) local_count_set_1 = 0;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    ....
    if(pass = 0){
        filter_local[atomic_inc(&local_count_set_1)] = 1;
    }
    ....
```

I'm hoping this fixes the issue // will update if not.

Aaaand that's a weekend I'll never get back.