# OpenCL cleanup output before reading it back

Tags: opencl

---

I'm fairly new to OpenCL and I got stuck at some point where I can't come up with a good solution myself.
Following scenario: I did write a Kernel for intersection calculation which is working just fine. I've got a number of rays and a number of lines. I am calculating wether there is an intersection happening for each ray against each line like so:

```
    foreach ray{
            foreach line{
                    pointXY = calculateIntersectionpoint();
                    }
            }
```

Now let's assume I input a total number of 25000 rays and 500 lines, I could in theory have 12500000 total intersection points.

---

However, this is not going to be the case practically speaking. My calculation will just set the intersection point to [0,0] if there's no intersection happening.
Now my problem is that I have got an outputarray of the size 12500000 or (rays*lines) which contains mostly zeros. Afterwards I do sort out the points where no intersection did happen - but this is very costly as most of my application time is wasted by sorting out those points.

---

I do read back the result from the device like this:

```
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(intersectionpointBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_long2) * numberOfRays * numberOfLines, &intersectionPoints[0]);
```

---

Now to my question: is there any way to have an output of variable size and "push_back" the output, every time my Kernel found an intersection point?
If this is not the case, do you have any suggestions I can work around this problem? 
I did already think about leaving the output on the device and do a sort in another Kernel - then just cut off the area I am not interested in. Though I am not sure how to implement that as of yet.

---

In case this is relevant: I am using OpenCL 1.1, my device is a Quadro 600 and I do use the opencl c++ wrapper.

---

thank you in advance

Comment: you can do atomic operations to sync threads to build output array, set an output parameter to tell size of output, send that output to host, then read only that size  of array from output. but buffers are constant size, just reading size could be sizeof(cl_long2) * outputParameter[0] or similar.

Comment: Are you just trying to reduce the number of [0,0] values returned? How many rays and lines do you typically pass to the kernel? What percentage on average would you say intersect?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/31517754/741692